# Building a rectangular pyramid

Tags: wood, joinery, dado, joints

I have made a set of Yahtzee™ dice from a 4x4 post. We have been using a bucket as the 'shaker cup'. I would like to construct a wooden 'cup'.
My concept is two use two identical rectangular pyramids, the rims of each would have holes bored for magnets in the rim, and the the points cut off, to allow for a handle and so that it can serve as a decorative storage container for the dice when not in use.

I plan on using slats of 1/2”x 3" aspen side by side with chamfered edges to make up each of the 4 'walls' of the pyramid. I'm struggling with figuring out how to join the edges of my pyramids.. biscuits.. four 1.5"x1 5" strips with angled rabbets cut out? I'm thinking this is the way to go, but trying to consider the various angles involved and how to transfer them to the wood.. it's making my head spin a little bit!

[image]

Thank you all for the help, and sorry the pic isn't the best, it's what I was able to quickly come up with on my phone

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. As these would be long-grain butt joints, assuming you bevel the edges accurately (these are bevels, not chamfers) you wouldn't need to reinforce them in any way because they should end up stronger than the wood around them.... even if you used a much stronger wood than aspen. Figuring out how you'll hold this shape firmly in clamps for the glue-up won't be cake though! If you need guidance on working out the angles, the things to look up are wooden bucket staves and hopper joints.

Comment: I trimmed a ton of white space out of the image, just to make the page more manageable.

Comment: for the angles, use a tool like: https://jansson.us/jcompound.html#npyramid

Comment: @dbx, wow that's useful!